# Recurrence relation of q-Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, q-analogs

I have seen in some papers the use of the recurrence fromula $S_q(n,k)= [k]_qS_q(n-1,k)+q^{k-1}S_q(n-1,k-1)$. However, I was wonderinghow we could prove this identity? I understand the proof of the recurrence for the regular Stirling numbers of the second kind, is this proof related to the one of the q-analog?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129880/combinatorial-interpretation-of-q-analogue-stirling-numbers) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108072/recurrence-for-q-analog-for-the-stirling-numbers) for two different approaches.